# iOS Transform Translate Animation not performing correctly

Tags: ios, transform

So I'm trying to perform a (seemingly) simple transform animation on a UIImageView by just moving it up 100 points. This is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:1 options:nil animations:^(void) {
    CGAffineTransform tf = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -100);
    [image setTransform:tf];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {} ];
```

It works...but it for some reason chooses a new origin for my UIImageView to start from. For example, if the image's original center coordinates are (300, 400), then by my code it should translate up 100 points to (300, 300). But for some reason, the code makes the image start a little bit lower than where it should, like around (300, 450), and then it'll move up 100 to (300, 350). How can I get it to do the animation from where the image is originally?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, so the problem is presumably somewhere else. Are you using Autolayout? How did you add the image view in the first place? If you don't have this code at all, does the image view appear in the "right" place?

Comment: Yeah, this is because you're using AutoLayout. You need to animate the constraints not the frame itself.

Comment: The image has no constraints, animating the constraints doesn't work. How do I turn AutoLayout off?  The image is placed in a xib layout file, not programmatically. Will doing it programmatically help solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use transformation for this procedure, then you should try to get original transform and translate it by 100 px.

```
[image setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(image.transform, 0, -100)];
```

Comment: Just tried this method, same exact thing happens. It can't seriously be this complicated to do a simple translate from (x,y) to (x-dx, y-dy) without anything else going wrong, but sadly I guess it is. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to translate the subview relative to its superview's coordinate system, you'll have more predictable results simply animating the center property:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0 animations:^{
    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x, image.center.y - 100);
}];
```

The transform property expresses an affine transform relative to the center property (or the layer's anchorPoint, if changed).

Comment: Can you elaborate? I tested the code and it worked fine for me. Can you provide more of the surrounding code for context?

Answer (score 0):

i'm having the same problem. if i want to translate my label 100 on the y-axis, it will start the animation -50 in the y, then moves it 100 from there. if i move it 200 in the y, it starts the animation -100 in the y, then moves it 200 from there. it's very frustrating.

@stackoverflowmaster, were you ever able to figure this out?

UPDATE: you must uncheck the "Use Auto Layout" option in the file inspector for whatever object you're trying to use. this took me way too long to figure out, hope it saves someone else some time.